# Is there an easy way to write this in Python?

Tags: python, numbers, max, min

```
        if(i-words < 0):
            start_point = 0
        else:
            start_point = i - words
```

Or is this the easiest way using min/max? This is for lists splicing.

I want start_point to always be 0 or above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better is to make the limiting more obvious

```
start_point = max(i - words, 0)
```

This way, anyone reading can see that you're limiting a value.

Using any form of `if` has the disadvantage that you compute twice `i - words`. Using a temporary for this will make more code bloat.

So, use `max` and `min` in these cases.

Comment: You need _min_ not _max_, guys.

Comment: Wrong, `min` limits on the above, `max` limits on the below

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
start_point = 0 if i - words < 0 else i - words
```

or

```
start_point = i - words if i - words < 0 else 0
```

or even better, the clearest way:

```
start_point = max(i - words, 0)
```

As Mihai says in his comment, the last way is not only clearer to read and write, but evaluates the value only once, which could be important if it's a function call.

Comment: It computes twice the same quantity. Of course, here there is a simple subtraction but one can use this example too when instead of `i` he would have `a_very_complex_function_taking_too_long_to_give_an_answer`

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that fact to the post.

Comment: `max` is correct. Observe: `max(-3, 0)` returns `0`, and `max(3, 0)` returns `3`, which is the intended behaviour. Also observe: `min(-3, 0)` returns `-3`, and `min(3, 0)` returns `0`, which are wrong results.

Comment: No.. it's `max`.. if the difference is less than 0, choose 0 (the larger value). otherwise choose the difference (the larger value)